# Why can't my .cshrc file be sourced automatically?

Tags: linux, shell

When I SSH to a certain Linux host, although my default shell is tcsh, the .cshrc file under my home directory is not sourced at all. I can't understand why this happens because from my understanding, if I'm using the tcsh, the .cshrc should be sourced anyway!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `man` page for `tcsh` says that if `~/.tcshrc` is not present then `~/.cshrc` is processed, so it may be that there is a `~/.tcshrc`.